# iOS webview app incorporating barcode scanner

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Hi I just started my adventure on IOS development and I am already stuck.

I have put together a simple webview app that is working just fine, its purpose is to load up a redeem page for certificate. I want to be able to pull the certificate information from the barcode into a text field on the page all inside the webview instead of someone having to type it in.

I have looked into multiple different threads and even a few items such as pic2go, zxing and others. However, I am still at a loss if something simple like this is possible.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you had any luck? We are looking for something similar.